# A 'forceful edit'? I think it was not very neccessary. Please tell me whether I am being rude or the point I raised is valid.

Tags: discussion, editing

I posted this question [Prove that $1<\frac{1}{1001}+\frac{1}{1002}+\frac{1}{1003}+\ldots+\frac{1}{3001}<\frac43$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/688432/prove-that-1-frac11001-frac11002-frac11003-ldots-frac13001#688432). I edited it quite a few times to add a context. However, when this user https://math.stackexchange.com/users/11176/tmm edited my post. I rolled it back, and immediately he/she said that I should not rollback any edit unless very necessary. I asked the reason but the user did not reply and re-edited the post. I don't want to follow rules setup by an individual but rather a community. Please enlighten me in this matter.

Comment: Here is [link to revision history](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/688432/revisions) of that post.

Comment: The reasons seem to be explained quite well by the comment of the user who edited.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft but the reason was not explained at all for the edit.

Comment: Yes it was. He said that titles should preferably not use display math in order to keep the front page clean.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Okay, I see that now, which I could not until a few moments ago. But, if that is the case, why did he edit the body? I think I was feeling more comfortable the way it was looking before the edit.

Comment: @Hawk: The roll it back to the point you were comfortable with, and then remove the display math from the title yourself.

Comment: @Hurkyl Ok. Thank you. I just hope I know how to do that. :)

Comment: @Hawk I think it looks better with more spacing.  Did you like the way it looked before because the $=$ signs were more aligned?  If so, consider using `$$\begin{eqnarray*}...$$`

Comment: I edited this into the question to demonstrate how to do it, feel free to roll it back if you don't like it.

Comment: @AlexanderGruber Thank you a lot.

Comment: I do not think that the tag "summation" is very appropriate, so while I agree with the title issue, the editor should not have insisted on that tag, because the asker did not ask to evaluate the sum.